# error: implicit declaration of function 'rl_replace_line' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, readline

I'm trying to implement rl_replace_line() in my code but when I try to compile it like that:

```
gcc -lreadline test.c -o test
```

I get this error message:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'rl_replace_line' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

however I think I used the good header files?
here is my code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <readline/readline.h>
# include <readline/history.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

char    *get_line()
{
    char *line;

    line = NULL;
    if (line)
    {
        free(line);
        line = NULL;
    }
    line = readline("Minishell>");
    if (line)
        add_history(line);
    return (line);
}

void    sig_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGINT)
    {
        printf("\n");
        rl_on_new_line();
        rl_replace_line("", 0);
        rl_redisplay();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char    *line;

    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
    line = get_line();
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, I hope you guys can help thanks!

Comment: Is that the only function that causes an error? Is that function declared in the readline related headers you include? Maybe that function is not available in the version of readline that you have installed.

Comment: Those are the only readline headers that I have found, I will try to see if it's a version issue

Comment: Do these headers contain a declaration of that function?

Comment: Try `gcc test.c -o test -lreadline` and see if it makes a difference. Linker options should be placed after compiler options.

Comment: The `rl_replace_line` function was added in Readline-4.3 which was released in 2002.

Comment: Is there a way to know what does a header file exactly contains?

Comment: Open the header file in your favourite editor. What more do you need?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer I couldn't have access to the Mac, I checked in the header file of readline.h and it contains the declaration of this function

Comment: BTW: you cannot use printf() in a signal handler.

Comment: @wildplasser why can't I?

Comment: Because I say so! and because printf() is not async-proof. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63461038/905902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by including the correct path with:

`-L .brew/opt/readline/lib` and `-I .brew/opt/readline/include`

now I compile like this and it's working:

```
gcc test.c -o test -lreadline -L .brew/opt/readline/lib -I .brew/opt/readline/include
```

Comment: Note this is because brew refuses to link readline. 

Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: readline
For compilers to find readline you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include"

Answer (score 1):

I solve the issue by finding the libreadline.a  with the command ==> find / -name libreadline.a 2> /dev/null.

The result is ==> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/readline/8.1.2/lib/libreadline.a

So I put the correct path for the compilation:
-L libs -lft -L /opt/homebrew/Cellar/readline/8.1.2/lib -lreadline.

No this is working perfectly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).